# How do I create One array from a sequence of arrays in Python using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to create one array which is a sequence of the following numpy arrays:
`np.random.normal([0, 0], size=(500, 2)), np.random.normal([5, 5], size=(500, 2)), np.random.normal([5, 0], size=(500, 2)), np.random.normal([0, 5], size=(500, 2))`
How can I merge them into one?
Tnx!

I tried using + operator but didn't work.

Comment: `+` is multiply for numpy arrays.  For lists (and strings) it is join.

Comment: Do you want a [500, 8] or do you want [2000, 2]?

Comment: I wanted [2000, 2].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the numpy concatenate() method to combine multiple arrays into one.

The syntax would be:

```
np.concatenate([np.random.normal([0, 0], size=(500, 2)), np.random.normal([5, 5], size=(500, 2)), np.random.normal([5, 0], size=(500, 2)), np.random.normal([0, 5], size=(500, 2))])
```

Hope this will solve your issue